# Kotlin - Clear Button listener for google's Place Autocomplete API onClick not called

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, onclicklistener, type-inference

I'm trying to create a listener for the clear button that comes from google's Place Autocomplete API. i called my `clearButton()` method in my fragment's `onViewCreated` method

**clearButton()**

```
placeAutocompleteFragment?.view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button)
    ?.setOnClickListener {
        View.OnClickListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cleared")
            it?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)?.setText("")
            it?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

now when i click on the clear button icon, the text doesn't get erased, nothing happens. I can still type in a new location though, but i can't clear it. my `Log.d` isn't getting displayed either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have android studio on this machine now to try, but I guess you can do something like

```
place_autocomplete_clear_button.onClick { place_autocomplete_search_input.text = "" }
```

where `place_autocomplete_clear_button` can be static import and `onClick` might be from `anko`

Comment: im not familiar with `anko` what is that?

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko super powerful lib developed by kotlin team to help you in android

Comment: `place_autocomplete_clear_button` is from the source code of `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`  though

Comment: then you'll want to keep a ref of the button

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had the method calls set up all wrong.

Here's how it should look like:

```
private fun clearButton() {
    placeAutocompleteFragment?.view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button)?.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cleared Button Clicked")
        it.visibility = View.GONE
        //do something
    }
}
```